# How to pass down multiple parameter through several functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's assume we have an exposed function (Level 0). We call this function with various parameter. Internally this function calls a second function (Level 1) but does not use any of the given parameters other than calling a third function (Level 2) with them as arguments. It might do some other stuff however.

My Question is. How can we pass down the arguments without creating too much noise in the middle layer function (Level 1)? I list some possible ways beneath. Be warned however that some of them are rather ugly and only there for completeness reasons. I'm looking for some established guideline rather than individual personal opinion on the topic

```
# Transport all of them individually down the road.
# This is the most obvious way. However the amount of parameter increases the
# noise in A_1 since they are only passed along
def A_0(msg, term_print):
    A_1(msg, term_print)

def A_1(msg, term_print):
    A_2(msg, term_print)

def A_2(msg, term_print):
    print(msg, end=term_print)


# Create parameter object (in this case dict) and pass it down.
# Reduces the amount of parameters. However when only reading the source of B1
# it is impossible to determine what par is
def B_0(msg, term_print):
    B_1({'msg': msg, 'end': term_print})

def B_1(par):
    B_2(par)

def B_2(par):
    print(par['msg'], end=par['end'])


# Use global variables. We all know the pitfalls of global variables. However
# in python there are at least limited to their module
def C_0(msg, term_print):
    global MSG, TERM_PRINT

    MSG = msg
    TERM_PRINT = term_print
    C_1()

def C_1():
    C_2()

def C_2():
    print(MSG, end=TERM_PRINT)


# Use the fact that python creates function objects. We can now append those
# objects. This makes some more 'localised' variables than shown before. However
# this also makes the code harder to maintain. When we change D_2 we have to alter
# D_0 as well even though it never directly calls it
def D_0(msg, term_print):
    D_2.msg = msg
    D_2.term_print = term_print
    D_1()

def D_1():
    D_2()

def D_2():
    print(D_2.msg, end=D_2.term_print)


# Create a class with the functions E_1, E_2 to enclose the variables.
class E(dict):
    def E_1(self):
        self.E_2()

    def E_2(self):
        print(self['msg'], end=self['end'])

def E_0(msg, term_print):
    E([('msg', msg), ('end', term_print)]).E_1()


# Create a nested scope. This make it very hard to read the function. Furthermore
# F_1 cannot be called directly from outside (without abusing the construct)
def F_0(msg, term_print):
    def F_1():
        F_2()

    def F_2():
        print(msg, end=term_print)

    F_1()


A_0('What', ' ')
B_0('is', ' ')
C_0('the', ' ')
D_0('best', ' ')
E_0('way', '')
F_0('?', '\n')
```

Comment: Such an underrated question! I am wondering, as of today, what would be your choice? Is there a best way? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to give a complete answer without knowing the full specifics of *why* there are so many parameters and so many levels of functions.  But in general, passing too many parameters is considered a [`code smell`](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TooManyParameters).

Generally, if a group of functions all make use of the same parameters, it means they are closely related in some way, and may benefit from encapsulating the parameters within a Class, so that all the associated methods can share that data.

> TooManyParameters is often a CodeSmell. If you have to pass that much
> data together, it could indicate the data is related in some way and
> wants to be encapsulated in its own class. Passing in a single
> data structure that belongs apart doesn't solve the problem. Rather,
> the idea is that things that belong together, keep together; things
> that belong apart, keep apart; per the OneResponsibilityRule.

Indeed, you may find that entire functions are completely unnecessary if all they are doing is passing data along to some other function.

```
class A():

    def __init__(self, msg, term_print)
        self.msg = msg
        self.term_print = term_print

    def a_0(self):
        return self.a_1()

    def a_1(self):
        return self.a_2()

    def a_2(self):
        print(msg, self.term_print)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I generally agree on the topic of too many parameters. However sometimes there is not much one can do about it. Functions like `plot` from `matplotlib` springs to mind. I'm not sure however about the class as I try to embrace functional programming.

Comment: I agree that if your primary design consideration is to be purely functional, and not do any assignment or store any state, then you have no option but to pass every possible parameter through your entire application.  For larger, broader, and more complex applications, especially ones that need to maintain some level of "state", functional design quickly becomes untenable, and is the reason why `structs` and `classes` were created.

Comment: I guess you are right. To me it seems however all the ways a showed before are bad in one way or an other (I also wrote about the class approach in E. Not that it matters but your class does actually something slightly different as you print an additional new line. In addition there are missing a few `self` to compile). I'll wait till tomorrow to give other people a chance to answer before accepting an answer.

Comment: Just to add one more query, Is it bad performance wise to pass a parameter through a lot of ufnctions before even using it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the meaning of your sets of parameters and of your function `A0`, using the `*args` notation may also be an option:

```
def A0(*args):
    A1(*args)
```

This allows any number of arguments to be passed to `A0` and will pass them on to `A1` unchanged. If the semantics of `A0` is just that, then the `*` notation expresses the intention best. However, if you are going to pass on the arguments in a different order or do anything else with them besides just passing them on as an opaque sequence, this notation is not a good fit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't like the splat operator in this case since it effectively is the same than solution B with the downside that it would silently execute in I mix up the order of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The book "Code Complete 2" by Steve McConnell suggests to use `globals`, their words are:

> **Reasons to Use Global Data**
>
> **Eliminating tramp data**
>
> Sometimes you pass data to a routine or class
> merely so that it can be passed to another routine or class. For
> example, you might have an error-processing object that's used in each
> routine. When the routine in the middle of the call chain doesn't use
> the object, the object is called "tramp data". Use of global variables can eliminate tramp data.
>
> **Use Global Data Only as a Last Resort**
>
> Before you resort to using global data
> consider a few alternatives:
>
> ***Begin by making each variable local and make variables global only as you need to***
>
> Make all variables local to individual routines initially. If you find
> they're needed elsewhere, make them private or protected class
> variables before you go so far as to make them global. If you finally
> find that you have to make them global, do it, but only when you're
> sure you have to. If you start by making a variable global, you'll
> never make it local, whereas if you start by making it local, you
> might never need it to make it global.
>
> ***Distinguish between global and class variables***
>
> Some variables are truly global in that they are accessed throughout
> the whole program. Others are really class variables, used heavily
> only within a certain set of routines. It's OK to access a class
> variable any way you want to within the set of routines that use it
> heavily. If routines outside the class need to use it, provide the
> variable's value by means of an access routine. Don't access class
> values direcly - as if they were global variables - even if your
> programming language allows you to. This advice is tantamount to
> saying "Modularize! Modularize! Modularize"
>
> ***Use access routines***
>
> Creating access routines is the workhorse approach to getting around
> problems with global data...

Link:
https://books.google.com/books/about/Code_Complete.html?hl=nl&id=LpVCAwAAQBAJ